# Spring: ApplicationEventPublisher @TransactionalEventListener Event not firing

Tags: spring

I need to modify our application so that a certain task is only done if the preceding database operation is successful. So I decided to use `@TransactionalEventListener`.

The database operations are successful but the `@TransactionalEventListener` never gets fired. I read the appropiate threads here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Hope you guys can help. ;)

**Edit (additional info):**
Neither the constructor nor `onApplicationEvent` in class `ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter` seems to get called. Execution did not stop at breakpoints. Could the spring event handling be deactivated?

My Code (all of it is part of one class called DataController):

Listener:

```java
@Component
public class ClearBusinessCaseListener {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void handleClearBusinessCaseEvent(ClearBusinessCaseEvent event) throws BusinessException {
        try {
            logger.info("handleEvent ClearBusinessCaseEvent");
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            logger.error("Elan-ID=" + event.elanId + ": Fehler bei handleClearBusinessCaseEvent!", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Event:

```java
public class ClearBusinessCaseEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
        String businesscaseId = "";
        String elanId = "";

        public ClearBusinessCaseEvent(Object source, String businesscaseId, String elanId) {
            super(source);
            this.businesscaseId = businesscaseId;
            this.elanId = elanId;
            logger.info("Konstruktor ClearBusinessCaseEvent");
        }
    }
```

Transactional Method:

```java
@Transactional
public String getSomethingFromSomewhere(String userSessionGuid, long tabId, int tabDbId)
        throws BusinessException {

        // Read data

        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new ClearBusinessCaseEvent(this, businesscaseId, elanId));

        // Get Documents from external Service

        // Save Documents

        // Modify existing Data Entities
}
```

Comment: Your usage of the annotation is wrong. It should go on a class of an `@Component` and should receive the event it reacts to. It shouldn't be on the event.

Comment: I added the Component annotation to ClearBusinessCaseEvent. Does not change anything. I am pretty sure that the TransactionalEventListener annotation goes to the method. All examples I could find do it this way (see docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html).

Comment: Adding `@Component` doesn't change a thing. Again add it to a standalone component that has a method with the `@TransationalEcventListener` annotation. The `@TransactionalEventLIstener` doesn't belong on a method in the event itself but a standalone component!. The method that has that annotation needs to receive the event.

Comment: Darn, I am sorry, I should have read your comment more carefully (english is not my native tongue). Basicly I am using the listener as an event. Thx 4 your help!

Comment: That did not change a thing unfortunatly. I changed my code in the original post. The TransactionalEventListener Method does not seem to get called. Do you (or anybody) see any other error?

Comment: Is the class with `@Component` detected by component-scanning? If not it simply doesn't exists/register as a listener and won't work. It looks like that is what is happening, judging from the fact the constructor isn't called.

Comment: Component-Scanning seems to have been deactivated. I added ```@Configuration``` and ```@ComponentScan``` to the surrounding class DataController and that worked. The Listener is now listed as a Bean and onApplicationEvent in ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter is called. isSynchronizationActive() returns true and there are no errors. But the method handleClearBusinessCaseEvent() in the listener is not called. Why could that be?

Comment: Different context. Also you should have a dedicated configuration class for the configuration don't shoehorn that into a controller. Your whole project seems to be consulted (do you use Spring BOot or not?). If you use plain spring you have 2 contexts, if your bean is in the parent it will receive events from the child, but if it is the other way around that won't happen. But we know too little about your project to answer that.

Comment: It works! Yeah! There was an obvious bug in the listener which caused an exception. Now everything ist working. Thx 4 your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thx too M. Deinum (see comments). The cause was a mix of lack of understanding and bugs. I edited the code example to reflect all that is needed for it to work.